# LuaTeX - " + a/e/i/o/u turning into umlauts

Tags: luatex, babel, german, shorthands

I have an issue where any vowel gets turned into an umlaut within a regular paragraph, without commands being used.

`"apple"` gets turned into `äpple"`, `"Question?" Anwser.` gets turned into `"Question?Änswer`

What could cause this? How do I fix this without having to escape every `"`?

Comment: you will have loaded babel with a language such as German that defines `"` to be a shortand to get an umlaut, you should not normally use `"` in text, use `\`\`` and `''`  or turn the shorthand off

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us whether you load the `babel` language package and, if so, with which language option(s).

Comment: Thank you!

`\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}`

Comment: Thank you very much @DavidCarlisle, using \`` works perfectly.

Comment: Alternatively, you can turn off that behavior with `\usepackage[shorthands=off,main=ngerman,english]{babel}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, the issue you've encountered is *not* specific to using LuaLaTeX to compile your document. It arises every bit as much with pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

If the `babel` package is loaded with `ngerman` as the (main) language option, various keyboard shorthands involving the `"` glpyh get enabled. One of these shorthands is that `"` followed by a vowel letter (`a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `A`, `E`, `I`, `O`, or `U`) is taken to mean that you wish to typeset the corresponding vowel letter with an Umlaut/diereris. Another `"`-shorthand is that `"s` gets typeset as `ß` ("scharfes Ess", "ess-zett").

Clearly, that's *not* what you intend to happen with `"apple"` and `"Answer"`. What to do? You could either disable babel's shorthands entirely by specifying the option `shorthands=off` (not generally recommended!), or you could train yourself to stop using `"` as a quoting character. Specifically, I would like to suggest that you load the `csquotes` package with the option `german=quotes`. That way, if you write `\enquote{apple}` and `\enquote{Answer}`, the words will be quoted using german-style lower and upper double quotes ("Gänsefüsschen"?).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes} % for \enquote macro

\begin{document}
"apple", "Answer" \quad vs.\quad \enquote{apple}, \enquote{Answer}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I fully agree that the best solution is to use `csquotes` and `\enquote`, but in addition I would argue that it *is recommended* to use `shorthands=off` except in special cases. IMO the benefit of having a special meaning of `"` is much lower than the pain it causes that such a common symbol behaves oddly.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger - Thanks. If the OP were to use the babel shorthands only to simplify inputting Umlauts, I'd wholeheartedly agree with the view that it's ok to recommend disabling the `"`-shorthands -- especially if the OP's keyboard is set up to enter `ä`, `ö`, `ü`, `Ä`, `Ö`, and `Ü` directly. However, some of the other shorthands, such as the ones that allow ligature suppression (`Auf"|lauf"|form`) and the hyphenation of the components of compound hyphenated words, are very useful in their own right and are generally worth preserving. Of course, the OP may not be using those shorthands...

Comment: I haven't familiarized myself enough with latex yet to use those shorthands, so I can appreciate that solution as well. It was a bit confusing to me to realize they're enabled by default considering I have those characters on my keyboard. 

Thank you so much @Mico for your detailed answer!